# Magento 2.4 Plugin afterGetPrice() - issues with Full Page Cache

Tags: magento2.4, plugin, full-page-cache

I am overriding the frontend price by using the Magento\Catalog\Model\Product plugin like so:

Sulman/Mymodule/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="sulman-product-model-frontend" type="Sulman\Mymodule\Plugin\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Sulman\Mymodule\Plugin\ProductPlugin.php:

```
<?php

namespace Sulman\Mymodule\Plugin;

class ProductPlugin
{

    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        return '123.45'; // just testing
    }
}
?>
```

This is working correctly **but** when FPC is enabled the prices do not update. (e.g. if I load the page, then change the return price to 789.99 then refresh frontend the price stays at 123.45 - If i then clear cache 789.99 then shows).

How can I get around the cache?

Thanks

*Magento 2.4.1*

Comment: On which page, you are trying

Comment: @AmitBera - This is on Product List page

Comment: @sulman Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @JancyAbraham - No. I ended using customer group pricing. It can be achieved using private data but that seemed like a convoluted method to me.